# Cannot add set to another set using set.add() in Python

Tags: python, set

I created a dictionary that maps name (string) to a set, and I defined it like this:

```
dict = {"a" : {"one", "two", "three"},
        "b" : {"one", "two", "three"},
        "c" : {"one", "two", "three", "four"}}
```

Then I used a list of keys like `["b", "c"]` to search in the keys of `dict`, and I want to concatenate the sets using `set.add()` like this:

```
output = set()
keys_to_search_for = ["b", "c"]
for i in keys_to_search_for:
    if i in dict.keys():
       output.add(dict[key])
```

This generated the error `unhashable type: 'set'`, but I checked the type of `output` and `dict[key]`, and they are both sets. I thought set.add() can concatenate 2 sets?

Comment: Do not you `dict` as a variable name! It is a reserved keyword in python.

Comment: @MusHusKat Generally good advice, but it isn't a keyword, it is just a name of a builtin.

Comment: @MusHusKat see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Comment: Thanks Flake - you are right, I was trying to sound simple at the expense of being inaccurate. But yes, avoid dict as it is a builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add one set to another set you should use `Set.update`

```py
a = {1, 2}
b = {2, 3}
a.update(b)

print(a)
```

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are add the value of the dictionary which itself is a set as an element to the output set. You need to do a union or update instead:

`output = output.union(dict[key])`

or

`output.update(dict[key])`

NOTE: Do not use the word dict as a variable!!

Comment: Note that `union` creates a new set and does not modify the original contents. For the code OP posted, only `update` should be used.